# Android Wifi Response too slow

Tags: java, android, performance, tcp, wifi

im currently developing an Android-Application in which data is transferred from a Server via http to the client (all in a local network). My intention is that this should happen in real-time, but actually (in some cases) Android wont accept the response instantly. This results in delays up to 200-3000(!)ms (for the time from setting off the package at the server until android receives it !) which is an absolutely unconvincingly behaviour. Wireshark tells me, that there are sometimes several tcp retransmissions (zero to five) - which means, the packages does not arrive in a appropriate speed for tcp. 
To confirm this, a simple Ping from Notebook/other android devices over wifi shows a latency of 150 in average (! the connectivity of each device is good enough !). In a local network i would expect a latency of up to 20ms over wifi in the bad cases..

Does anybody have experience with that behavior and can give me some advice?

I know that mobile devices always have a lot of energy saving options - in that case - how can i disable this for my application?

Comment: What version of Android do you use? If it is 4.0.3... good luck! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661940/losing-link-while-using-wifi-with-android-4-0-3

Comment: i'm getting over 1 second sometimes!

Comment: Hello from 2022. On Android 9 connecting via a variety of access point brands, I have seen 400ms on all of them. Some of them >800ms (for server with 0.5ms latency). Seems to happen more often at the beginning of a communication streak, possibly indicating a power-save bug.

Comment: Maybe poor bandwidth or still try exploring different protocols

Comment: Try checking you server as well. There might be contribution to latency by the server itself... Also, try checking the latency of your wifi on android device at any other website (the speed testing websites).

Answer (score 5):

I believe "Wi-Fi optimization" is enabled by default system-wide on android. This option minimizes battery usage. You can disable it by going into the wifi settings where you choose a wifi connection, then press menu -> advanced.

Additional info:
http://www.pocketables.com/2013/10/android-tip-turn-off-wifi-optimization-if-youre-having-trouble-using-certain-apps-over-wifi.html

On android 13: Settings -> Network & internet -> Adaptive connectivity

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have already done this. Also i did the #*0011..something on my mobile phone to disable wifi energy saving - without any success. Still my latencies are about 100ms with resulting lag while transmission over tcp. but anyway thanks!

Comment: @MarcoHübers Maybe there are too many interfering signals on the same wifi channel. Try using Wifi Analyzer to see if there is a better channel that you can set your router to use.

[wifi analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en)

Comment: I dont really think that this is the problem. I already installed a seperate router to configure a standalone network with only two devices on a complete own network. But i will try wifi analyser and let u know.

Comment: In a standalone network in a own Channel the responses arrive without retransmissions. But still not really "instant". There is still a lag about ~500ms..

Comment: @MarcoHübers If this lag is specific to your android device, I might try running your application on a different android device. If all devices on your network have high latency between each other, I would try a different wifi router.

Comment: The provided link may be out of date. On Android 9, the Settings > Wi-Fi > Advanced menu does not have a "Wi-Fi optimization" box to uncheck.

Answer (score 1):

In developer options:

- Enable `Wifi scan throtting`
- Enable `Tethering Hardware Acceleration`
- Disable `Wifi Optimiation`
- Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` and
  `android:largeHeap="true"` to `AndroidManifest application`

And also if you define app in `Game Category` some manufactures has custom speedUp implementations like Xiaomi and Samsung, for quick test this `Game Enhancment Implemantations` open a game as `Popup Window` then test your application ;)

Comment: I make speed test every time with a game which inside in PopupWindow. Via this latency down and transmit speed up efficently :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a new trick with Android 10+:

```
adb shell cmd wifi force-low-latency-mode enabled
```

See https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-low-latency for reference. Didn't fix my ping issues though.